# Android Button Bar - buttonBarButtonStyle leaves gap between buttons

Tags: android, xml

I'm having some trouble with the built in Android button bar styling. After giving a width of 0 and weight of 1 to each of my buttons, there's still about a 1px gap in between the two buttons (see image).

What is the best way to get rid of that gap? Why is it even there to begin with?

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_bar"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/details_scroll_view"
    android:paddin="0dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_dark_blue"
        android:text="button1"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_light_blue"
        android:text="button2"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[button bar][1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kwf4.png

Comment: Check out http://developer.android.com/samples/BorderlessButtons/res/layout/sample_main.html#l71 too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` then you can use something like

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_light_blue"
        android:text="button2"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" />  //this will put the left edge of this button at the right edge of button1
```

Comment: I still would like to preserve equal weighting for the buttons, with equal width. The centering function of layout_weight of 1 with width of 0dp only appears to work for linear layouts. Relative layout does remove the gap though...

Comment: You can still keep them centered and the same size.

Answer (score 0):

This will only change the size of the button. You need to use the `layout_margin` attribute, like this:

```
android:layout_marginLeft=<insert value here>
```

Comment: Pretty hackish, but it looks like the following works: `android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"`

Answer (score 0):

The space you are seeing is actually a divider.
To hide those dividers, just add

```
android:showDividers="none"
```

to the `LinearLayout`.